# page control in uiscrollview

Tags: objective-c, xcode

i ve created a uiscrollview containing a page control which loads the images from resource bundle..everything works good.i m able to scroll through different images..the problem is if i m to click the corresponding pagecontrol(dot), i m not able to navigate to the corresponding image....could u guys help me out below is the code...the below code works perfectly fine

```
// Email.h

@interface Email : UIViewController<UIScrollViewDelegate>
{
   UIPageControl *pageControl;
   UIScrollView *scroller;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UIPageControl *pageControl;
@property (nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UIScrollView *scroller;

-(IBAction)clickPageControl:(id)sender;

@end


// Email.m

@implementation Email
@synthesize pageControl,scroller;

-(IBAction)clickPageControl:(id)sender
{
   int page=pageControl.currentPage;
   CGRect frame=scroller.frame;
   frame.origin.x=frame.size.width=page;
   frame.origin.y=0;
   [scroller scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
}

-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
   int page = scrollView.contentOffset.x/scrollView.frame.size.width;
   pageControl.currentPage=page;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   self.title=@"Press Photos";
   for (int i=1; i<10; i++)
   {
      UIImageView *images=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:
        [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.jpg",i]]];
      images.frame=CGRectMake((i-1)*320, 0, 320, 460);
      [scroller addSubview:images];
      [images release];
   }
   scroller.delegate=self;
   scroller.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320*9, 460);
   scroller.pagingEnabled=YES;

   pageControl.numberOfPages=9;
   pageControl.currentPage=0;
}
```

Comment: You should really use code tags to display your code so it's readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
frame.origin.x=frame.size.width=page;
```

should be

```
frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * page;
```

Comment: thanks that totally worked...i got one more query.ive got 8 images(means 8 dots)..if i m to click the fifth dot(pagecontrol)i want the 5th image to get loaded in scrollview...not each image get loaded until the 5th image is seen in scroll view...thanks in advance

Comment: UIPageControl doesn't support direct jumping to a page. If you really want it done, consider adding a `UITapRecognizer` to the page control and handle the taps. Judge based on the frame and tap location, which page the user is interested in and change the page accordingly.